# MouseDown, MouseMove while MouseDown, MouseUp eventlisteners react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this block of code:

```html
<div class="time-grid-item gap-1 d-flex justify-content-between">
   <div class="grid-row" id="row-0-spaceID-1" style="width: 56.4375px; height: 576px;">
      <div class="reservation-card d-flex flex-column justify-content-around align-items-center" style="margin-top: 73px; width: 56.4375px; background-color: rgb(66, 245, 84); height: 62px;"><span style="font-size: 0.6vw;">Catachasatie avond</span><span style="font-size: 0.6vw;">10:00:51 - 11:45:28</span></div>
      <div class="reservation-card d-flex flex-column justify-content-around align-items-center" style="margin-top: 10px; width: 56.4375px; background-color: rgb(66, 245, 84); height: 18.2px;"><span style="font-size: 0.6vw;">test</span><span style="font-size: 0.6vw;">11:59:33 - 12:31:36</span></div>
      <div class="reservation-card d-flex flex-column justify-content-around align-items-center" style="margin-top: 55px; width: 56.4375px; background-color: rgb(66, 245, 84); height: 287px;"><span style="font-size: 0.6vw;">test</span><span style="font-size: 0.6vw;">14:00:27 - 22:00:54</span></div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid-row" id="row-1-spaceID-2" style="width: 56.4375px; height: 576px;"></div>
   <div class="grid-row" id="row-2-spaceID-3" style="width: 56.4375px; height: 576px;"></div>
   <div class="grid-row" id="row-3-spaceID-4" style="width: 69.3438px; height: 576px;">
      <div class="reservation-card d-flex flex-column justify-content-around align-items-center" style="margin-top: 100px; width: 69.3438px; background-color: rgb(66, 245, 43); height: 367.4px;"><span style="font-size: 0.6vw;">Battlefield 5</span><span style="font-size: 0.6vw;">10:46:06 - 21:00:34</span></div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid-row" id="row-4-spaceID-5" style="width: 69.3438px; height: 576px;">
      <div class="reservation-card d-flex flex-column justify-content-around align-items-center" style="margin-top: 109px; width: 69.3438px; background-color: rgb(66, 245, 43); height: 323.6px;"><span style="font-size: 0.6vw;">436</span><span style="font-size: 0.6vw;">10:59:05 - 20:00:52</span></div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid-row" id="row-5-spaceID-6" style="width: 170.375px; height: 576px;">
      <div class="reservation-card d-flex flex-column justify-content-around align-items-center" style="margin-top: 217px; width: 170.375px; background-color: rgb(68, 59, 166); height: 179px;"><span style="font-size: 0.6vw;">test</span><span style="font-size: 0.6vw;">14:00:54 - 19:00:02</span></div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid-row" id="row-6-spaceID-7" style="width: 99.5312px; height: 576px;">
      <div class="reservation-card d-flex flex-column justify-content-around align-items-center" style="margin-top: 253px; width: 99.5312px; background-color: rgb(52, 137, 235); height: 107px;"><span style="font-size: 0.6vw;">r323</span><span style="font-size: 0.6vw;">15:00:37 - 18:00:56</span></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I create the mouseDown, mousemove while mousedown, mouseUp event listener on the element with class **grid-row** in React?

ps: i want to create something like the google calendar click drag time selector

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent

Comment: Your code is not React JSX, what have you done so far to convert it? (And, adding events to elements in JSX is covered in the documentation, so [it is worth reading](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html))

Comment: @DBS it is made in React JSX, but if i show u the code for that part it does not add any additional value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   export default function SelectionArea() { 
   let startX = 0;
   let startY = 0;
   let endX = 0;
   let endY = 0;
   let isSelecting = false;
   useEffect(() => {
   setTimeout(() => {
   const rootElement: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById("root");

  const selectionDiv: HTMLElement | null =
    document.getElementById("selectionDiv");

  const selectionAreaElement: HTMLElement | null =
    document.getElementById("selectionArea");

  if (selectionDiv && workSpaceElement) {

    document.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
      mouseUpEventHandler(e, selectionDiv);
    });

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) =>
      mouseDownEventHandler(e, selectionDiv)
    );

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
      mouseMoveEventHandler(e, selectionDiv);
    });
  }
}, 2000);

return () => {
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", eventListenerHandler);
  document.removeEventListener("keydown", eventListenerHandler);
};
 }, []);

const mouseDownEventHandler = (e: MouseEvent, selectionDiv: HTMLElement) => {
console.log("mousedown");
if (isSelecting) return;
isSelecting = true;
startX = e.clientX;
startY = e.clientY;

if (selectionDiv) {
  selectionDiv.style.border = "1px solid #3B82F6";
  selectionDiv.style.backgroundColor = "#85B2F9";
  selectionDiv.style.opacity = "0.5";
  selectionDiv.style.left = startX + "px";
  selectionDiv.style.top = startY + "px";
  selectionDiv.style.width = "0";
  selectionDiv.style.height = "0";
  selectionDiv.style.position = "absolute";
  selectionDiv.style.display = "block";
  selectionDiv.style.zIndex = "3";
}
};

const mouseMoveEventHandler = (
e: MouseEvent | null,
selectionDiv: HTMLElement
) => {
if (e) {
  console.log("mousemove");
  if (!isSelecting) return;
  endX = e.clientX;
  endY = e.clientY;

  let width = endX - startX;
  let height = endY - startY;
  if (width < 0 && selectionDiv) {
    width = width * -1;
    selectionDiv.style.left = startX - width + "px";
  }

  if (height < 0 && selectionDiv) {
    height = height * -1;
    selectionDiv.style.top = startY - height + "px";
  }

  if (selectionDiv) {
    selectionDiv.style.width = width + "px";
    selectionDiv.style.height = height + "px";
  }
  /*if (selectionDiv) {
      getCrossedElement(selectionDiv.getBoundingClientRect(), dispatch);
    }*/
  }
  };

const mouseUpEventHandler = (e: MouseEvent, selectionDiv: HTMLElement) => {
if (e) {
  if (!isSelecting) return;
  console.log("mouseup");
  if (selectionDiv) {
    selectionDiv.style.display = "none";
  }
  isSelecting = false;
}
};

return (
<div className="selectionArea-container" id="selectionArea-container-id">
  <Tooltip id="addButton" style={tooltipStyle} />

  <div id="selectionArea"></div>
</div>
);
}
```

The index.html where the selection div is located

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
<meta
  name="description"
  content="Web site created using create-react-app"
/>
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
<!--
  Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
  It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
  Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

  Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
  work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
  Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
-->
<title>Some example</title>
</head>
<body>
 <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="selectionDiv"></div>
<div id="root">
</div>
<script type="module" src="/src/index.tsx"></script>
<!--
  This HTML file is a template.
  If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

  You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
  The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

  To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
  To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
  -->
</body>
</html>
```